# I want to insert the data of the students in the database.please elaborate to me and how to show the data in the table specially date-of-birth

Tags: python, django

I have seven fields for entering the data in the database , e.g(Student id,first name, last name,major,phone, gpa and date-of-birth)

But the criteria is that i have to create the Date class containing Day,Month,Year as fields and i'm struggling to do this.
I also want know to create the different fields in the models file and how the data will entered from the form. 
How is this work in the views file.
Below the html code for fetching data from the user and i use the input fields in the type of text(type="text")
But for date i used the(type="Date")

The views file,in this file i just entered the data in the simplest manner cause i don't know how to split the day, month and year for entering the data in the string.

The Models File Code,in this file i created the two table classes for entering the data.
the first class is Date class which will store the data separately for the day, month and year
The another table class is Student, firstly which will use the date class with the forgeinkey to store the data in the table along with the other fields.

Another Requirement is to Create the Class Date containing Day, Month and Year as Fileds
HTML CODE:-

```
 <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="birth">
  </div>
```

VIEWS CODE:-

```
def studentinsert(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        phonenumber=request.POST['phonenumber']
        gpa=request.POST['gpa']
        birth=request.POST['birth']
        s=Student()
        s.sname=iid
        s.sphone=phonenumber
        s.sgpa=gpa
        s.sdate=birth
        s.save()
        return HttpResponse("Data is Inserted")
    else:
        return render(request,"student/insertstudent.html")
```

MODELS FILE CODE:-

```
class Date(models.Model):
    day=models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    month=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Student(models.Model):
    sdate=models.ForeignKey(Date,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sid=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sfname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    smajor=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sphone=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sgpa=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This is my code i've done it.......

Comment: add a models.DateField() in Student model. you don't need separate model for date.

Comment: But the requirement is to create a Date Class Containing Day, Month, and Year as Fields, so now what should i do.

Comment: you can get day, month, year by date.day, date.month, date.year

Answer (score 0):

forms.py file is where the django documentation recommends you place all your forms code; to keep your code easily maintainable. In your app create forms.py file and import the forms from django. Use this form class in your views to render the form on template. For more please refer the django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/

```
from django import forms

BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = ['1980', '1981', '1982']
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = [
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
]

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    birth_year = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                       choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,)
```

Please

Comment: what is forms.ModelForm means and and when i import the extras its give an error saying (no name 'extras' in module django.forms)

Comment: @GaganSharma i have edited the post for django 2.2 as earlier answer was for django 1.8.